# how to solve this problem The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an Apple submission certificate. (-19011)

Tags: iphone, xcode, adhoc

I am getting stuck with this error while building Ad hoc distribution profile.

Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an Apple submission certificate. (-19011)

i had follow the same process as it is mentioned at apple developer program.

Certificates, Provision Profiles and Entitlements....all things are valid....!

then where is the problem ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have solved this problem, it was a certificate issue, so i revoke & renew all certificates and generate provision profiles again.

Thanks.