# Application failed code signing

Tags: iphone, app-store, code-signing

when i use Archive from run i get following warning. Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid, contains disallowed entitlements, or it was not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate. (-19011). Im going to upload my app to appstore. App will upload or not?

Comment: Are you using the Distribution Certificate? Are you sure you aren't using the Development Certificate instead?

Answer (score 0):

it was a certificate issue, so i revoke & renew all certificates and generate provision profiles again.

[Check Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5415043/how-to-solve-this-problem-the-signature-was-invalid-or-it-was-not-signed-with-a)

Thanks.

Comment: I deleted my all provisioning profile. And revoke new certificate for development and distribution. And create new provisioning profile for development. Download all those things and set to xcode. Again getting same warning. Is apple allowed my .ipa to appstore?

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2250/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009933-CH1-TNTAG32